# Unable to mount root fs over NFS

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, startup, root-filesystem

I am attempting to set up the first (of many) Raspberry Pis running Pidora (a Fedora Remix) to boot from an NFS share. It is my goal to eventually place a dozen or more Raspberry Pis in the datacenter I use to power several different services for my infrastructure and clients and hopefully replace some of the smaller VPS nodes that I am currently using.

My configuration in cmdline.txt is:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=<serverip>:/fake/path,nolock ip=dhcp elevator=deadline rootwait
```

On the Pi, the output I see is:

```
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from <router>, my address is <clientip>
IP-Config: Complete:
device=eth0, hwaddr=<macaddress>, ipaddr=<clientip>, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=<routerip>
host=<clientip>, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
bootserver=<routerip>, rootserver=<serverip>, rootpath=
nameserver0=<routerip>
(It pauses for a bit here)
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy
VFS: Cannot open root device "nfs" or unknown-block(2,0); error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
.....
```

The export configuration is:

```
/fake/path        <clientip>(rw,no_root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

On the NFS Server (an OpenVZ Container), the output I see in the /var/log/messages is:

```
Aug 22 23:24:01 vps-4178 rpc.mountd[928]: authenticated mount request from <clientip>:783 for /fake/path (/fake/path)
Aug 22 23:24:38 vps-4178 rpc.mountd[928]: authenticated mount request from <clientip>:741 for /fake/path (/fake/path)
Aug 22 23:25:25 vps-4178 rpc.mountd[928]: authenticated mount request from <clientip>:752 for /fake/path (/fake/path)
Aug 22 23:26:12 vps-4178 rpc.mountd[928]: authenticated mount request from <clientip>:876 for /fake/path (/fake/path)
```

To test, I've made sure I can mount (non-root) from both the Pi and another machine and it worked.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be wrong or how to narrow it down?

**UPDATE:**

The process has gotten slightly further. The server is still showing the same message, however the client is now saying " is not responding, still trying".

Here is the tcpdump (tcdump -vv 'port not 22') during the process:

```
tcpdump: listening on venet0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
02:27:49.396600 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56458, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:27:49.396694 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22318, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:27:49.396700 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22318, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:49.396701 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22318, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:49.396963 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34369, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 72)
    <serverhostname>.57067 > <redacted2>.domain: [udp sum ok] 45505+ PTR? <redacted>.in-addr.arpa. (44)
02:27:49.400054 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 121)
    <redacted2>.domain > <serverhostname>.57067: [udp sum ok] 45505 q: PTR? <redacted>.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/0 <redacted>.in-addr.arpa. PTR <clienthostname>. (93)
02:27:49.400289 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34372, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 73)
    <serverhostname>.51421 > <redacted2>.domain: [udp sum ok] 15808+ PTR? <redacted3>.in-addr.arpa. (45)
02:27:49.401603 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 115)
    <redacted2>.domain > <serverhostname>.51421: [udp sum ok] 15808 q: PTR? <redacted3>.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/0 <redacted3>.in-addr.arpa. PTR <redacted2>. (87)
02:27:50.496543 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56459, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:27:50.496627 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22319, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:27:50.496634 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22319, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:50.496636 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22319, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:52.694985 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56460, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:27:52.695058 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22320, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:27:52.695064 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22320, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:52.695066 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22320, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:57.105354 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56461, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:27:57.105451 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22321, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:27:57.105456 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22321, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:27:57.105458 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22321, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:05.914058 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56462, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:28:05.914130 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22322, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:28:05.914137 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22322, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:05.914138 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22322, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:07.014579 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56463, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:28:07.014665 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22323, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:28:07.014672 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22323, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:07.014674 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22323, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:09.216009 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 56464, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 144)
    <clienthostname>.3541049940 > <serverhostname>.nfs: 116 read fh Unknown/01000401D2255200F6209D570C172001AA2F2645000000000000000000000000 4096 bytes @ 516096
02:28:09.216102 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22324, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname>.nfs > <clienthostname>.3541049940: reply ok 1472 read REG 100755 ids 0/0 sz 1630184 nlink 1 rdev ffffffff fsid 579d20f6 nodeid 120170c a/m/ctime 1408774668.892909 1404929018.000000 1408747025.202589
02:28:09.216107 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22324, offset 1480, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
02:28:09.216109 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22324, offset 2960, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1264)
    <serverhostname> > <clienthostname>: udp
```

Comment: I'd replace the Raspberry Pis with small VPS nodes.

Comment: Can't tell from your output if the mount is succeeding or not.  I would tcpdump from server and see if it is.  If the pi is booted from SD but given the same IP, can you mount /fake/path?  Do you have root access to the data on it?

Comment: @bowlofred I added the tcpdump to the original post. The Pi can be booted from the SD, given the same IP and can mount the /fake/path. I do have root access to the data.

Comment: The conversation doesn't look right to me.  The server is receiving the NULL NFS call, but it isn't sending a reply.  I don't know what the rpc calls are doing.  You might open that in wireshark and see what it's trying to do.  But for now it seems the server doesn't want to respond to the client about the mount.  Could be pending some verification, could be something else wrong.

Comment: @bowlofred - thank you, your suggestion helped me to get a bit further. I'm now experiencing a slightly different issue. The client is saying "server <serverip> not responding, still trying" and the server is still showing the same information in the log. I updated the tcpdump above with information from the new test if you're willing to take a look.

Comment: Again, I can see the result but not the cause.  In the dump you can see the client is asking for data, the server responds, but then the client asks for the same data again (4096 bytes @ 516096).  Why?  Could be bug in client, client doesn't think the data is good or right format...  See the fsid:579d20f6  Do you have a file with that inode in the /fake/path filesystem?  Might give a clue as to what file is being requested.

Comment: @bowlofred thanks again for your help. I ended up compiling a custom kernel (with both NFS and ipv6 support) and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The stock kernel of Pidora doesn't support nfsroot so you'll have to compile your own kernel. I guess that's why they say Fedora is bleeding edge...

Comment: Such a pointed answer would benefit greatly from links to supporting information or relevant documentation.

Comment: Robert is correct. Back in August at least, as I commented, I had to compile a custom kernel to add NFS support to Pidora.