# Network boot: Unable to mount root fs via NFS

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, nfs, raspbian

I'm trying to boot my Raspberry Pi 3 over the network, but it has trouble mounting the root partition via NFS.

I verified from a different machine that the NFS volume is mountable. I also looked at similar questions here (e.g.
[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204872/nfs-root-filesystem-doesnt-mount-at-boot), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151723/unable-to-mount-root-fs-over-nfs)), but unfortunately they weren't helpful. So any help would be gladly appreciated.

Also neither `debug` nor `nfsrootdebug` kernel parameters provided any more information to debug this problem.

**Hardware:** Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
**OS:** RaspiOS Lite ARM64, based on Debian Buster
**Kernel:** 5.10.17

**Boot log**:

```
Sending DHCP requests ..., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.178.1, my address is 192.168.178.24
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, hwaddr=b8:27:eb:e6:f9:aa, ipaddr=192.168.178.24, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.178.1
     host=192.168.178.24, domain=fritz.box, nis-domain=(none)
     bootserver=192.168.178.1, rootserver=192.168.178.38, rootpath=
     nameserver0=192.168.178.1
     ntpserver0=192.168.178.1
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS.
```

**cmdline.txt** (line breaks for readability):

```
console=serial0,115200
console=tty1
debug
nfsrootdebug
root=/dev/nfs
nfsroot=192.168.178.38:/volume2/pxe/pi2--b8-27-eb-e6-f9-aa/,vers=4.1,proto=tcp rw
ip=dhcp
rootwait
elevator=deadline
```

**/etc/exports** (configured through Synology NAS, line breaks for readability):

```
/volume2/pxe 192.168.178.0/24
(rw,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
```

Comment: Does your raspi linux kernel support that filesystem? I guess no. Your boot-image is probably a CD/DVD image; they use different filesystems, like CDFS, ISO 9660, UDF, make sure your kernel supports these.

Comment: @paladin Kernel is 5.10.17, so yes nfs is supported (RaspiOS is Debian Buster). Both boot and root partitions are extracted on the NAS (ext4), booted via pxe.

Comment: The image is probably a disc image with partitions / multiple records, you need to mount it correctly.

Comment: Both partitions were mounted from the disk image (boot as vfat, root as ext4) using the sectors determined by `fdisk -l -u=sectors imagename>.img`, multiplied by block size of 512.

Comment: Your IP-Config output indicates the DHCP answer included the `rootserver`, but the `rootpath` (DHCP option code 17) seems to be blank. Perhaps the use of DHCP causes the `nfsroot=` option from the cmdline.txt to be overridden? Or perhaps order matters, and the latter `ip=dhcp` overrides the previous `nfsroot=` specification with the DHCP information, causing the NFS share path to be lost? Try supplying the root filesystem path through DHCP if possible, and/or switching the order of the `nfsroot=...` and `ip=dhcp` kernel command line options.

Comment: Did you use a loop device? Otherwise you cannot mount multiple partitions from a single image file at the same time just by using the mount command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764271/mounting-multiple-partitions-from-a-disk-image-file (look at the accepted answer)

Comment: @paladin Yes, I did use a loop device. Thanks for the link, I found this solution quite elegant and adopted it. Unfortunately, it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: @telcoM Unfortunately I can't pass the root path via DHCP, as I was planning to netboot multiple devices with distinct root directories (distinguished by MAC address), which I can't provide for each device individually. Switching the `ip=dhcp` and `nfsroot=...` kernel parameters didn't have any effect.